# Flutter: How to change state of the widget when a certain function has been called?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth, widget

### How it looks like

I've a got bluetooth in my flutter app based on flutter_blue package (^0.8.0). I can connect with my external device and exchange the data. To read data from bluetooth following function is being called when data arrived :

```
void parseBleMsg(List<int> data) {
  print("Data1: $data");
  /* Parse the income message */
  msgID = data[0];
  luxValue = data[1];
  print("lux: $luxValue");
  print("msgid: $msgID");
}
```

The parseBleMsg() callback is being set by using specific flutter_blue package methods like setNotifyValue() and .value.listen() :

```
late BluetoothCharacteristic colsRX;

void setNotifyRX() async {
    await colsRX.setNotifyValue(true);

    subscription = colsRX.value.listen(
      (event) {
        parseBleMsg(event);
      },
    );
  }
```

In one of my app pages I have got a multiple number of buttons which are a custom statefull widgets :

```
class MeasurementPoint extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  final double leftPos;
  final double topPos;
  const MeasurementPoint(
      {required this.id, required this.leftPos, required this.topPos});

  @override
  State<MeasurementPoint> createState() => _MeasurementPointState();
}

class _MeasurementPointState extends State<MeasurementPoint> {
  bool pointState = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: widget.leftPos,
      top: widget.topPos,
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Material(
          color: pointState ? Colors.green : Styles.primaryColor,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () async {
              Bluetooth().bleWrite();
              lastClicked = widget.id;
              /* TODO : AWAIT FOR BLUETOOTH RESPONSE AND THEN CHANGE STATE */
              // setState(() {
              //   pointState = !pointState;
              // });
            },
            child: const SizedBox(
                width: 25, height: 25, child: Icon(Icons.sensors)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### What I want to achieve

As you can see, there is the "TODO" In onTap method. Inside onTap() method I want to send the data through bluetooth to my external device (it works fine) and after that I want to await for the response and then rebuild the widget, to simply change the color of the button as an indicator that the response frame has been received.
The problem I have is that I have no idea, how to await in onTap(), or how in other way rebuilt that widget with new color when I will receive the response from bluetooth.

Comment: await Bluetooth().bleWrite(); does not work for you?

Comment: @eamirho3ein, Bluetooth().bleWrite() is responsible for sending the data (request call), after that I want to await for frame which will arrive after that Bluetooth().bleWrite() call